# R - calculate annual population conditional on survival in every year

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I have a data frame with three columns: birth_year, death_year, gender.
I have to calculate total alive male and female population for every year in a given range (1950:1980).
The data frame looks like this:

```
birth_year   death_year   gender
1934         1988         male
1922         1993         female
1890         1966         male
1901         1956         male
1946         2009         female
1909         1976         female
1899         1945         male
1887         1949         male
1902         1984         female
```

The person is alive in year x if death_year > x & birth year <= x

The output I am looking for is something like this:

```
year    male    female
1950    3       4
1951    2       3
1952    4       3
1953    4       5
.
.
1980    6       3
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(year = map2(1950,1980, seq)) %>% unnest(year) %>% 
mutate(isalive = case_when(year >= birth_year & year < death_year ~ 1, TRUE ~ 0))  %>% 
group_by(year, gender) %>% summarise(alive = sum(isalive)) %>% 
pivot_wider(names_from = gender, values_from = alive) %>% print( n = 50)
`summarise()` regrouping output by 'year' (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 31 x 3
# Groups:   year [31]
    year female  male
   <int>  <dbl> <dbl>
 1  1950      4     3
 2  1951      4     3
 3  1952      4     3
 4  1953      4     3
 5  1954      4     3
 6  1955      4     3
 7  1956      4     2
 8  1957      4     2
 9  1958      4     2
10  1959      4     2
11  1960      4     2
12  1961      4     2
13  1962      4     2
14  1963      4     2
15  1964      4     2
16  1965      4     2
17  1966      4     1
18  1967      4     1
19  1968      4     1
20  1969      4     1
21  1970      4     1
22  1971      4     1
23  1972      4     1
24  1973      4     1
25  1974      4     1
26  1975      4     1
27  1976      3     1
28  1977      3     1
29  1978      3     1
30  1979      3     1
31  1980      3     1
```

Data used:

```
df
# A tibble: 9 x 3
  birth_year death_year gender
       <dbl>      <dbl> <chr> 
1       1934       1988 male  
2       1922       1993 female
3       1890       1966 male  
4       1901       1956 male  
5       1946       2009 female
6       1909       1976 female
7       1899       1945 male  
8       1887       1949 male  
9       1902       1984 female
```

Comment: Note 1976 has an extra female death because there was a female who died in that year. This doesn't satisfy the condition df$death_year > x. So you probably want year < death_year.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple base R solution. Summing a logical vector will get you your count of alive or dead because TRUE is 1 and FALSE is 0.

```
number_alive <- function(range, df){
  sapply(range, function(x) sum((df$death_year > x) & (df$birth_year <= x)))
}

output <- data.frame('year' = 1950:1980,
                     'female' = number_alive(1950:1980, df[df$gender == 'female']),
                     'male' = number_alive(1950:1980, df[df$gender == 'male']))
# year female male
# 1  1950    4      3
# 2  1951    4      3
# 3  1952    4      3
# 4  1953    4      3
# 5  1954    4      3
# 6  1955    4      3
# 7  1956    4      2
# 8  1957    4      2
# 9  1958    4      2
# 10 1959    4      2
# 11 1960    4      2
# 12 1961    4      2
# 13 1962    4      2
# 14 1963    4      2
# 15 1964    4      2
# 16 1965    4      2
# 17 1966    4      1
# 18 1967    4      1
# 19 1968    4      1
# 20 1969    4      1
# 21 1970    4      1
# 22 1971    4      1
# 23 1972    4      1
# 24 1973    4      1
# 25 1974    4      1
# 26 1975    4      1
# 27 1976    3      1
# 28 1977    3      1
# 29 1978    3      1
# 30 1979    3      1
# 31 1980    3      1
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach uses an `ifelse` to determine if alive (1) or dead (0).

**Data:**

```r
df <- "birth_year   death_year   gender
1934         1988         male
1922         1993         female
1890         1966         male
1901         1956         male
1946         2009         female
1909         1976         female
1899         1945         male
1887         1949         male
1902         1984         female"

df <- read.table(text = df, header = TRUE)
```

**Code:**

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
library(purrr)

df %>% 
  mutate(year = map2(1950,1980, seq)) %>% 
  unnest(year) %>% 
  select(year, birth_year, death_year, gender) %>% 
  mutate(
    alive = ifelse(year >= birth_year & year <= death_year, 1, 0)
  ) %>% 
  group_by(year, gender) %>% 
  summarise(
    is_alive = sum(alive)
  ) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = gender,
    values_from = is_alive
  ) %>% 
  select(year, male, female)
```

**Output:**

```
#> # A tibble: 31 x 3
#> # Groups:   year [31]
#>     year  male female
#>    <int> <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1  1950     3      4
#>  2  1951     3      4
#>  3  1952     3      4
#>  4  1953     3      4
#>  5  1954     3      4
#>  6  1955     3      4
#>  7  1956     3      4
#>  8  1957     2      4
#>  9  1958     2      4
#> 10  1959     2      4
#> # … with 21 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>